# How does the Maven project select appropriate version dependencies

Tags: maven

When importing dependencies, how to select an appropriate version, or how to understand the compatibility between different versions to make a selection, so as to prevent the incompatibility between different versions from causing large bugs in program operation.
As shown in the figure below, there are multiple candidates when selecting mybatis version. At this time, if you import MySQL, JUnit and other tools, how to match appropriate versions of each other to avoid incompatibility?[The image when importing the dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or6gM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is:

- search the internet
- read documentation
- try and see what happens

Comment: Reading the release notes of the libs/tools etc.